# How to get distinct count of many fields in one row using best possible method

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my demos database, in which I join them based on 2 keys, here I would like to count distinct of matched result,

my first table

```
MariaDB [demos]> select * from main_info;
+------+------+-------+-------+----------+
| key1 | key2 | info1 | info2 | date     |
+------+------+-------+-------+----------+
|    1 |    1 |    15 |    90 | 20120501 |
|    1 |    2 |    14 |    92 | 20120601 |
|    1 |    3 |    15 |    82 | 20120801 |
|    2 |    1 |    17 |    90 | 20130302 |
|    2 |    2 |    16 |    88 | 20130601 |
+------+------+-------+-------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And my second table

```
MariaDB [demos]> select * from product1;
+------+------+--------+--------------+
| key1 | key2 | serial | product_data |
+------+------+--------+--------------+
|    1 |    1 |      0 | NaN          |
|    1 |    1 |      1 | NaN          |
|    1 |    1 |      2 | NaN          |
|    1 |    1 |      3 | NaN          |
|    1 |    2 |      0 | 12.556       |
|    1 |    2 |      1 | 13.335       |
|    1 |    3 |      1 | NaN          |
|    1 |    3 |      2 | 13.556       |
|    1 |    3 |      3 | 14.556       |
|    2 |    1 |      0 | 12.556       |
|    2 |    1 |      1 | 13.553       |
|    2 |    1 |      2 | NaN          |
+------+------+--------+--------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So distinct count of field serial is as follows, where serial is not zero

```
MariaDB [demos]> select count(distinct a.key1,a.key2) as serial_count from main_info a,product1 b where a.key1=b.key1 and a.key2=b.key2 and b.serial !=0;
+--------------+
| serial_count |
+--------------+
|            4 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and distinct count of field product_data is as follows where product_data is not NaN

```
MariaDB [demos]> select count(distinct a.key1,a.key2) as product_count from main_info a,product1 b where a.key1=b.key1 and a.key2=b.key2 and b.product_data !='NaN';
+---------------+
| product_count |
+---------------+
|             3 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In my original application I have many columns in my table, finally I would like to get result like below using single query, at present I am doing multiple query using PHP which is taking long time because for example if I have 100 columns, I have to execute function 100 times like above, so please someone guide me to speed up my application

```
+--------------+---------------+
| serial_count |product_count  |
+--------------+---------------+
|    4         |    3          |
+--------------+---------------+
```

**Below is structure of tables**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `main_info`;
CREATE TABLE `main_info` (
  `key1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `info1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `info2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


LOCK TABLES `main_info` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `main_info` VALUES (1,1,15,90,20120501),(1,2,14,92,20120601),(1,3,15,82,20120801),(2,1,17,90,20130302),(2,2,16,88,20130601);
UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product1`;
CREATE TABLE `product1` (
  `key1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_data` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


LOCK TABLES `product1` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (1,1,0,'NaN'),(1,1,1,'NaN'),(1,1,2,'NaN'),(1,1,3,'NaN'),(1,2,0,'12.556'),(1,2,1,'13.335'),(1,3,1,'NaN'),(1,3,2,'13.556'),(1,3,3,'14.556'),(2,1,0,'12.556'),(2,1,1,'13.553'),(2,1,2,'NaN');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

**I didn't understand this why datetype changed, if I run on terminal**

```
$ mysql -u root -p demos -e 'select key1,if(key1 !=0,key1,999.999) as `test1` from main_info'
Enter password: 
+------+-------+
| key1 | test1 |
+------+-------+
|    1 | 1.000 |
|    1 | 1.000 |
|    1 | 1.000 |
|    2 | 2.000 |
|    2 | 2.000 |
+------+-------+
```

I expect it should be integer if `IF` condition is true

Comment: `if(key1 !=0,key1,999.999)`. MySQL doesn't know, if the condition will be true. So it desides to use a data type that can store `999.999`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a single query using *conditional aggregation*:

```sql
select count(distinct if(b.product_data !='NaN',a.key1, null),  
                      if(b.product_data !='NaN',a.key2, null)) as product_count,
       count(distinct if(b.serial !=0,a.key1, null),  
                      if(b.serial !=0,a.key2, null)) as serial_count                     
from main_info a
inner join product1 b on a.key1=b.key1 and a.key2=b.key2
```

**Output:**

```
product_count   serial_count
-----------------------------
3               4
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d3c98/1)

**Edit:** Credit goes to @Paul Spiegel

The query can be simplified using `CONCAT`:

```sql
select count(distinct if(b.product_data !='NaN', 
                         CONCAT(a.key1, ',', a.key2), 
                         null)) as product_count,
       count(distinct if(b.serial !=0, 
                         CONCAT(a.key1, ',', a.key2), 
                         null)) as serial_count                     
from main_info a
inner join product1 b on a.key1=b.key1 and a.key2=b.key2
```

Comment: Thank  you so much, could you please explain

Comment: @user3637224 The trick is to include the `WHERE` predicates of your queries *inside* the `COUNT` aggregate function. This way `count` takes into account **only** records that satisfy the corresponding predicate, namely  `b.product_data !='NaN'` or `b.serial !=0`.

Comment: Suppose if I have to include some more `where` statement how ?

Comment: I didn't get this syntax `count(distinct if(b.product_data !='NaN',a.key1, null),  
                      if(b.product_data !='NaN',a.key2, null)) as product_count`

Comment: This means: count *distinct* values of `a.key1`, `a.key2` **only when** `b.product_data !='NaN'`. So this is equivalent to your initial query.

Comment: You can prevent duplication of the condition if you concatenate key1 and key2: `count(distinct if(b.product_data !='NaN',concat(a.key1,',',a.key2), null)) as product_count`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Good remark. I will incorporate it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you

Comment: If I run this command on my terminal `mysql -u root -p demos -e 'select key1,if(key1 !=0,key1,999.999) as test1 from main_info'` even though `IF` condition is true data type has been changed , 1 became 1.000

Comment: Sir I have one more question but little bit different scenario and table data changed, can you please help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538092/mysql-group-concat-of-repeated-keys-and-count-of-repeatation-of-multiple-columns)