# Mysql group_concat of repeated keys and count of repetition of multiple columns in 1 query ( Query Optimization )

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

This question is regarding query optimization to avoid multiple call to database via PHP.

So Here is scenario, I have two tables one contains information you can call this as reference table and another one is data table, fields `key1` and `key2` are common in both table, based on these fields, we can join them.

I don't know whether query can be made even simpler than what I am doing right now, what I want to achieve is as follows :

> I would like to find distinct `key1,key2,info1,info2` from `main_info`
>   table, whenever serial value is less than 10 and `key1,key2` of both
>   table matches, and then group them by `info1,info2`, while grouping
>   count the repeated `key1,key2` for duplicates of  `info1,info2` fields
>   and `group_concat` those keys

**Contents of table `main_info`**

```
MariaDB [demos]> select * from main_info;
+------+------+-------+-------+----------+
| key1 | key2 | info1 | info2 | date     |
+------+------+-------+-------+----------+
|    1 |    1 |    15 |    90 | 20120501 |
|    1 |    2 |    14 |    92 | 20120601 |
|    1 |    3 |    15 |    82 | 20120801 |
|    1 |    4 |    15 |    82 | 20120801 |
|    1 |    5 |    15 |    82 | 20120802 |
|    2 |    1 |    17 |    90 | 20130302 |
|    2 |    2 |    17 |    90 | 20130302 |
|    2 |    3 |    17 |    90 | 20130302 |
|    2 |    4 |    16 |    88 | 20130601 |
+------+------+-------+-------+----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Contents of table `product1`**

```
MariaDB [demos]> select * from product1;
+------+------+--------+--------------+
| key1 | key2 | serial | product_data |
+------+------+--------+--------------+
|    1 |    1 |      0 | NaN          |
|    1 |    1 |      1 | NaN          |
|    1 |    1 |      2 | NaN          |
|    1 |    1 |      3 | NaN          |
|    1 |    2 |      0 | 12.556       |
|    1 |    2 |      1 | 13.335       |
|    1 |    3 |      1 | NaN          |
|    1 |    3 |      2 | 13.556       |
|    1 |    3 |      3 | 14.556       |
|    1 |    4 |      3 | NaN          |
|    1 |    5 |      3 | NaN          |
|    2 |    1 |      0 | 12.556       |
|    2 |    1 |      1 | 13.553       |
|    2 |    1 |      2 | NaN          |
|    2 |    2 |     12 | 129          |
|    2 |    3 |     22 | NaN          |
+------+------+--------+--------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Via PHP I group fields `info1` and `info2` of table `main_info`, in current context `serial`,`product_data` of table `product1`, multiple times one after another (here I am running query twice as you can see)**

**For field `serial` - 1st query**

```
MariaDB [demos]> select * , count(*) as serial_count,GROUP_CONCAT(key1,' ',key2) as serial_ids from 
    -> (
    -> SELECT distinct 
    -> if(b.serial  < 10,a.key1,null) AS `key1`,
    -> if(b.serial  < 10,a.key2,null) AS `key2`,
    -> if(b.serial  < 10,a.info1,null) AS `info1`, 
    ->         if(b.serial  < 10,a.info2,null) AS `info2`
    -> FROM main_info a inner join product1 b on  a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2= b.key2
    -> ) as sub group by info1,info2
    -> ;
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+
| key1 | key2 | info1 | info2 | serial_count | serial_ids  |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+
| NULL | NULL |  NULL |  NULL |            1 | NULL        |
|    1 |    2 |    14 |    92 |            1 | 1 2         |
|    1 |    3 |    15 |    82 |            3 | 1 3,1 4,1 5 |
|    1 |    1 |    15 |    90 |            1 | 1 1         |
|    2 |    1 |    17 |    90 |            1 | 2 1         |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**For field `product_data` - 2nd query**

```
MariaDB [demos]> select * , count(*) as product_data_count,GROUP_CONCAT(key1,' ',key2) as product_data_ids from 
    -> (
    -> SELECT distinct 
    -> if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key1,null) AS `key1`,
    -> if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key2,null) AS `key2`,
    -> if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.info1,null) AS `info1`, 
    ->         if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.info2,null) AS `info2`
    -> FROM main_info a inner join product1 b on  a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2= b.key2
    -> ) as sub group by info1,info2
    -> ;
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------------+------------------+
| key1 | key2 | info1 | info2 | product_data_count | product_data_ids |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------------+------------------+
|    1 |    2 |    14 |    92 |                  1 | 1 2              |
|    1 |    3 |    15 |    82 |                  3 | 1 3,1 4,1 5      |
|    1 |    1 |    15 |    90 |                  1 | 1 1              |
|    2 |    2 |    17 |    90 |                  3 | 2 2,2 3,2 1      |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**I would like to get output like this using one query, Group by info1, info2**

```
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| key1 | key2 | info1 | info2 | serial_count | serial_ids  | product_data_count | product_data_ids |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| NULL | NULL |  NULL |  NULL |            1 | NULL        |               NULL | NULL             |
|    1 |    2 |    14 |    92 |            1 | 1 2         |                  1 | 1 2              |
|    1 |    3 |    15 |    82 |            3 | 1 3,1 4,1 5 |                  3 | 1 3,1 4,1 5      |
|    1 |    1 |    15 |    90 |            1 | 1 1         |                  1 | 1 1              |
|    2 |    1 |    17 |    90 |            1 | 2 1         |                  3 | 2 2,2 3,2 1      |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

**Below is structure of tables**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `main_info`;
CREATE TABLE `main_info` (
  `key1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `info1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `info2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


LOCK TABLES `main_info` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `main_info` VALUES (1,1,15,90,20120501),(1,2,14,92,20120601),(1,3,15,82,20120801),(1,4,15,82,20120801),(1,5,15,82,20120802),(2,1,17,90,20130302),(2,2,17,90,20130302),(2,3,17,90,20130302),(2,4,16,88,20130601);
UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product1`;
CREATE TABLE `product1` (
  `key1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_data` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


LOCK TABLES `product1` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (1,1,0,'NaN'),(1,1,1,'NaN'),(1,1,2,'NaN'),(1,1,3,'NaN'),(1,2,0,'12.556'),(1,2,1,'13.335'),(1,3,1,'NaN'),(1,3,2,'13.556'),(1,3,3,'14.556'),(1,4,3,'NaN'),(1,5,3,'NaN'),(2,1,0,'12.556'),(2,1,1,'13.553'),(2,1,2,'NaN'),(2,2,12,'129'),(2,3,22,'NaN');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Someone please help me to get result in one query.

Comment: I do not see where the rows with the `NULL` values are coming from.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Its I think because serial value 22, 12 does not evaluate to true but it match main_info table, I really don't know why so, but if I run above query I get NULL

Comment: Those rules in the query make it really hard to understand what your queries are really attempting to do.  It is not just a simple join, then.

Comment: I would like to find distinct key1,key2,info1,info2 from main_info table, whenever serial value is less than 10 and key1,key2 of both table matches, and then group them by info1,info2, while grouping count the repeated key1,key2 for duplicates of  info1,info2 fields and concat those keys

Comment: @user3637224 please response on my answer, I'm sure it give right output at-least..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
SELECT 
     key1, key2, info1, info2, 
     SUM(Scount) AS serial_count, GROUP_CONCAT(Skey1, ' ', Skey2) AS serial_ids,
     SUM(Pcount) AS product_data_count, GROUP_CONCAT(Pkey1, ' ', Pkey2) AS product_data_ids 
FROM 
(

   SELECT DISTINCT 
     IF(b.serial  < 10 OR b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key1, NULL) AS `key1`,
     IF(b.serial  < 10 OR b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key2, NULL) AS `key2`,
     IF(b.serial  < 10 OR b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.info1, NULL) AS `info1`, 
     IF(b.serial  < 10 OR b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.info2, NULL) AS `info2`,
     IF(b.serial  < 10,a.key1, NULL) AS `Skey1`,
     IF(b.serial  < 10,a.key2, NULL) AS `Skey2`,
     IF(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key1, NULL) AS `Pkey1`,
     IF(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key2, NULL) AS `Pkey2`,
     IF(b.serial < 10, 1, NULL) AS `Scount`,
     IF(b.product_data IS NOT NULL, 1, NULL) AS `Pcount`
   FROM main_info a INNER JOIN product1 b ON  a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2= b.key2

   UNION ALL

   SELECT DISTINCT
     NULL AS `key1`,
     NULL AS `key2`,
     NULL AS `info1`,
     NULL AS `info2`,
     NULL AS `Skey1`,
     NULL AS `Skey2`,
     NULL AS `Pkey1`,
     NULL AS `Pkey2`,
     IF(serial > 9, 1, NULL) AS `Scount`,
     IF(product_data IS NULL, 1, NULL) AS `Pcount`
   FROM product1 WHERE serial > 9 xor product_data IS NULL

) AS sub GROUP BY info1,info2
```

**RESULT (data from question)**

```
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| key1 | key2 | info1 | info2 | serial_count | serial_ids  | product_data_count | product_data_ids |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  | 1            | NULL        | NULL               | NULL             |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| 1    | 2    | 14    | 92    | 1            | 1 2         | 1                  | 1 2              |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| 1    | 3    | 15    | 82    | 3            | 1 3,1 4,1 5 | 3                  | 1 3,1 4,1 5      |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| 1    | 1    | 15    | 90    | 1            | 1 1         | 1                  | 1 1              |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

**RESULT (data from comment)**

```
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| key1 | key2 | info1 | info2 | serial_count | serial_ids  | product_data_count | product_data_ids |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  | 1            | NULL        | 1                  | NULL             |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| 1    | 2    | 14    | 92    | 1            | 1 2         | 1                  | 1 2              |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| 1    | 3    | 15    | 82    | 3            | 1 3,1 4,1 5 | 3                  | 1 3,1 4,1 5      |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| 1    | 1    | 15    | 90    | 1            | 1 1         | 1                  | 1 1              |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| 2    | 4    | 16    | 88    | 1            | 2 4         | 1                  | 2 4              |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| 2    | 1    | 17    | 90    | NULL         | NULL        | 3                  | 2 1,2 2,2 3      |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

**NOTE:**

There is something that I can really understand about the base logic behind the question, so answer mainly base on expected result. Such as if group field (`info1` and `info2`) are null, the other result will always null except for `serial_count` and `product_data_count` that can be 1 or null, did you really meant to get that? Notice that this answer use another sub query with `UNION ALL` to satisfy that.

Comment: Can  you explain this, I didn't understand the logic

Comment: why did you use xor there ?

Comment: Buddy I got, its working great, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 3):

How about combining your two queries with a JOIN?

SQL:

```
 SELECT
    tbl1.key1, tbl1.key2, tbl1.info1, tbl1.info2, tbl1.serial_count, tbl1.serial_ids,
    tbl2.product_data_count, tbl2.product_data_ids
 FROM 
 (
select * , count(*) as serial_count,GROUP_CONCAT(key1,' ',key2) as serial_ids from 
 (
 SELECT distinct 
 if(b.serial  < 10,a.key1,null) AS `key1`,
 if(b.serial  < 10,a.key2,null) AS `key2`,
 if(b.serial  < 10,a.info1,null) AS `info1`, 
         if(b.serial  < 10,a.info2,null) AS `info2`
 FROM main_info a inner join product1 b on  a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2= b.key2
 ) as sub group by info1,info2
 ) tbl1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (
select * , count(*) as product_data_count,GROUP_CONCAT(key1,' ',key2) as product_data_ids from 
 (
 SELECT distinct 
 if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key1,null) AS `key1`,
 if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key2,null) AS `key2`,
 if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.info1,null) AS `info1`, 
         if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.info2,null) AS `info2`
 FROM main_info a inner join product1 b on  a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2= b.key2
 ) as sub group by info1,info2
 ) tbl2
 ON tbl1.info1 = tbl2.info1 AND tbl1.info2 = tbl2.info2
 ORDER BY 3,4
 ;
```

Output:

```
mysql>  SELECT
    -> tbl1.key1, tbl1.key2, tbl1.info1, tbl1.info2, tbl1.serial_count, tbl1.serial_ids,
    -> tbl2.product_data_count, tbl2.product_data_ids
    ->  FROM
    ->  (
    -> select * , count(*) as serial_count,GROUP_CONCAT(key1,' ',key2) as serial_ids from
    ->  (
    ->  SELECT distinct
    ->  if(b.serial  < 10,a.key1,null) AS `key1`,
    ->  if(b.serial  < 10,a.key2,null) AS `key2`,
    ->  if(b.serial  < 10,a.info1,null) AS `info1`,
    ->          if(b.serial  < 10,a.info2,null) AS `info2`
    ->  FROM main_info a inner join product1 b on  a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2= b.key2
    ->  ) as sub group by info1,info2
    ->  ) tbl1
    ->  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ->  (
    -> select * , count(*) as product_data_count,GROUP_CONCAT(key1,' ',key2) as product_data_ids from
    ->  (
    ->  SELECT distinct
    ->  if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key1,null) AS `key1`,
    ->  if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.key2,null) AS `key2`,
    ->  if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.info1,null) AS `info1`,
    ->          if(b.product_data IS NOT NULL,a.info2,null) AS `info2`
    ->  FROM main_info a inner join product1 b on  a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2= b.key2
    ->  ) as sub group by info1,info2
    ->  ) tbl2
    ->  ON tbl1.info1 = tbl2.info1 AND tbl1.info2 = tbl2.info2
    ->  ORDER BY 3,4
    ->  ;
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| key1 | key2 | info1 | info2 | serial_count | serial_ids  | product_data_count | product_data_ids |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
| NULL | NULL |  NULL |  NULL |            1 | NULL        |               NULL | NULL             |
|    1 |    2 |    14 |    92 |            1 | 1 2         |                  1 | 1 2              |
|    1 |    3 |    15 |    82 |            3 | 1 3,1 4,1 5 |                  3 | 1 3,1 4,1 5      |
|    1 |    1 |    15 |    90 |            1 | 1 1         |                  1 | 1 1              |
|    2 |    1 |    17 |    90 |            1 | 2 1         |                  3 | 2 2,2 3,2 1      |
+------+------+-------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>  select version();
+-----------------+
| version()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.10-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: plus 1 , but this method fails for example tbl1 returns 5 rows, and tbl2 was supposed to return 6 rows, output it shows only 5 rows, you can just truncate both tables and insert this data, `INSERT INTO main_info VALUES (1,1,15,90,20120501),(1,2,14,92,20120601),(1,3,15,82,20120801),(1,4,15,82,20120801),(1,5,15,82,20120802),(2,1,17,90,20130302),(2,2,17,90,20130302),(2,3,17,90,20130302),(2,4,16,88,20130601),(2,5,16,88,20130601);`

Comment: `INSERT INTO product1 VALUES (1,1,0,'NaN'),(1,1,1,'NaN'),(1,1,2,'NaN'),(1,1,3,'NaN'),(1,2,0,'12.556'),(1,2,1,'13.335'),(1,3,1,'NaN'),(1,3,2,'13.556'),(1,3,3,'14.556'),(1,4,3,'NaN'),(1,5,3,'NaN'),(2,1,11,'12.556'),(2,1,11,'13.553'),(2,1,11,'NaN'),(2,2,11,'129'),(2,3,11,'NaN'),(2,4,9,NULL),(2,4,19,'11');`

Comment: You can try to changeJOe LEFT OUTER JOIN to OUTET JOIN.

Comment: outer join is not giving result as expected

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your quote it seems to me you want to do something like this ([SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/742b39/1/0)):

```
SELECT
  m.info1,
  m.info2,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(m.key1, ' ', m.key2)) key_count,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(m.key1, ' ', m.key2) ORDER BY m.key1, m.key2) key_pairs,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.serial) serial_count,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.serial ORDER BY p.serial) serials,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_data) data_count,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.product_data ORDER BY p.product_data) product_data
FROM
  main_info m INNER JOIN
  product1 p ON p.key1 = m.key1 AND p.key2 = m.key2
WHERE
  p.serial < 10
GROUP BY
  m.info1,
  m.info2
```

Count distinct values and list them, is this correct? You can't just group by info1, info2 and also have columns for key1 or key2 in the result (e.g. min(key1) or max(key2) would work). I adjusted this in the query above, although it is quite different from your result it might be what you actually need, maybe with a few changes.

Comment: Sorry this is not giving result as expected